# Profiling Summary Report in the console

Tags: devmode

I've noticed a few blog posts referring to the Profiling Summary Report. In the blog posts the author shows examples of it showing on Chrome's devtools. I'm in dev mode but can't see this on my Chrome devtools. Is there some more configuration needed to show this in the newest versions of Craft?

[image: Image from Nystudio's post on cache]

Answer (score 1):

The picture you posted is from Craft 2 when [Dev Mode](https://craftcms.com/guides/what-dev-mode-does) is enabled.  In that case, it would output the debugging and profiling information to the browser's console.

In Craft 3, that has been replaced by the Debug Toolbar.  There is a good article here on what it is and how to use it:  https://nystudio107.com/blog/profiling-your-website-with-craft-cms-3s-debug-toolbar

Comment: Thanks. I've been using the debug toolbar..but just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything out :)